# 'react-dnd' does not contain an export named 'DragDropContext'

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, drag, react-dnd

I tried to use react dnd in my react web application. I create a js file call `withDnDContext.js`. When I compile it, I received an error `'react-dnd' does not contain an export named 'DragDropContext'`. My react-dnd version is latest one 9.3.2

This is my `withDnDContext.js`

```
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd'
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend);
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 11):

If you use the latest version of react dnd, `DragDropContext` has been replaced with `DndContext`. Please see [React-DnD V8](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

My top component looks like this;

```
import { React } from 'react';
import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

export default class MyApp {
    render() {
        return (
            <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <MyComp />
            </DndProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/dnd-provider) or [overview](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/overview) could be really helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping HTML5Backend with curly braces solved the problem for me.

```
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'
```